# Mailgun email validation api not working in my form

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, email-validation, mailgun

I want to use mailgun email validation API in my form but its not giving any kind of status.

I am implementing in laravel 5.2 project.

form: http://laravel.io/bin/42YyX

Comment: What response do you get if any?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj page just refreshes

Comment: You can check the `preserve` checkbox in your browser's console log to get the js related error messages from your form submission.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj console is showing 2 errors: 1) forget:87 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mailgun_validator is not a function 2) styles1.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onfocus' of null

Comment: Your first error means you have not included mailgun library on your page before using its function in your custom javascript. If that is not the case, another possibility could be that you might have included jQuery library more than once on this page. Please try to eliminate these errors.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj first error is gone still not working

Comment: [SOLVED] multiple jquery files were there

Comment: Glad to know you got your problem solved :)

Comment: You can close your question or answer it yourself giving the explanation for users with similar issue in future.

Comment: OK , how to close the question?

Comment: You can select your own answer as the working solution for this question. There is no need for closing this question then.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] multiple jquery files were there